# 404 when serving react application in docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, containers

I've create a react application with create-react-app and have build a docker image with the following docker file.

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
RUN npm install -g serve
EXPOSE 80
CMD serve -p 80 -s build
```

When running the container and accessing port 80 on localhost I'm met with "404 the requested path could not be found". The container is run with the command `docker run -p 80:80 "image name" and the output is "Accepting connections at http://localhost:80" What could be the reasons for the 404 and what can i do to fix it?

Comment: what happen if you change the app port and change in the docker file too, maybe you have port `80` used by a running web server, e.g `apache` or `nginx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking at the documentation of serve...](https://github.com/zeit/serve#readme) You are copying `/app/build` from the `builder` container in to `/app` on the new container and then calling `serve` with a folder name of `build`, which does not exist. (`-s` doesn't take a parameter`)

Comment: Thanks. Changing the COPY line to `COPY --from=builder /app/build app/build` did the trick.